# Purpose of boolean logic in For loop

Tags: c#

```
for (int i = 0; i < OurObject.Entities.SubEntities.Count && OurObject.Entities.SubEntities[i].Fields != null; i++ )
{
    // Do something with  OurObject.Entities.SubEntities[i].Fields.SomeFieldName1
    // Do something with  OurObject.Entities.SubEntities[i].Fields.SomeFieldName2
    // etc.    
}
```

I'm trying to glean the intent of this logic (written by someone else, a long time ago). Elsewhere in this application, some operation is performed on every SubEntity in a collection. In this case however, wouldn't this logic limit processing to at most ONE SubEntity? Or would it somehow skip processing for SubEntities that don't have Fields?

Background: Apparently this code has flown under the radar for a long time, but now someone noticed that it may not be performing correctly. I don't have data for exercising this code/debugging.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, it limits processing to all the subentities with fields before the first subentity *without* a field.

In LINQ terms, it's equivalent to:

```
foreach (var subEntity in OutObject.Entities.SubEntities
                                            .TakeWhile(x => x.Fields != null))
```

I'd be very suspicious of it. I suspect it's *meant* to be the equivalent of:

```
foreach (var subEntity in OutObject.Entities.SubEntities
                                            .Where(x => x.Fields != null))
```

... which would be achieved by putting the condition inside the body of the loop, e.g.

```
for (int i = 0; i < OurObject.Entities.SubEntities.Count; i++) 
{
    if (OurObject.Entities.SubEntities[i].Fields == null)
    {
        continue;
    }
    // Do something with  OurObject.Entities.SubEntities[i].Fields.SomeFieldName1
    // Do something with  OurObject.Entities.SubEntities[i].Fields.SomeFieldName2
    // etc.    
}
```

Comment: Thanks for suggenting both Linq & non-Linq alternatives for expressing this logic.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't that processing will stop after one subentity, but it will stop when it encounters a subentity without any fields.

Answer (score 0):

Using the nature of a for loop, yes, potentially this would stop at the first SubEntity that doesn't have and fields attached. Even if they were trying to grab *any* `SubEntities` with `Fields` or the *first*, this is surely not the way to go about it.

Answer (score 0):

The logic stops at the first entity that doesn't fulfill the condition, i.e. the first one where Field == null, or at the last entity in the SubEntities collection otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

It iterates over the SubEntities until it either reaches the end, or hits one without fields. All SubEntities which come after the first without fields will be ignored, even if they have fields themselves.

Sometimes you want this behavior, but in this case it looks like a bug to me, and the coder didn't want to break, but continue instead, which would handle all SubEntities with Fields.

But I'd refactor this code to use Linq, i.e. either `TakeWhile` or `Where` since that makes the intend clear.

```
for (int i = 0; i < OurObject.Entities.SubEntities.Count && OurObject.Entities.SubEntities[i].Fields != null; i++ )
{ 
  ...
}
```

is equivalent to

```
for (int i = 0; i < OurObject.Entities.SubEntities.Count;  i++ )
{ 
  if(OurObject.Entities.SubEntities[i].Fields == null)
    break;//Perhaps he intended `continue` and not break here
  ...
}
```